# ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification hold my app in iOS6

Tags: ios6

In my app,I used ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification to update my own photo album ,but in iOS6, when i delete some photos ,then back to my app, it holded.

anybody know why?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Do you perform any operation in the uikit upon receiving this notification? If this is the case, do these operations on the main thread using something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // do uikit stuff
});
```

This may be the source of the hang. Had the same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "it holded"? On my machine, no ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification is received. If this is what you mean, I agree, and it's a clear bug. There is apparently no built-in reliable way to detect that the photo library has changed.